Comparing a string that is reversed (palindrome)
I am using the below function and getting the below output. Can someone please explain why.
It prints out that they are equal after the for loop finishes but when compared the logic says they are not equal.
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

 bool palindrome;


// Define is_palindrome() here:

 bool is_palindrome(std::string text){
  std::string backwards = "";
  for (int i = text.length();i >= 0; i--){
  backwards = backwards + text[i];
   std::cout << backwards << std::endl;
  }
  std::cout << backwards << " and " << text << std::endl;
  if (text == backwards){
    std::cout << "they are equal" << std::endl;
    palindrome = true;
  }
  else{
    std::cout << "they are not equal" << std::endl;
    palindrome = false;
  }
  return palindrome;
}

int main() {
  
  std::cout << is_palindrome("madam") << "\n";
  
  
}

OUTPUT

m
ma
mad
mada
madam
madam and madam
they are not equal
0


Side note: nothing in this code needs the extra stuff that std::endl does. Use '\n' to end a line unless you have a good reason not to.

Something in your actual code is different from what you've shown here. Your output displays 1 as the value returned by the function; taking the "they are not equal" branch would have set palindrome to false, and the output would have shown 0.

Tip: think about how you'd solve this problem with pencil and paper. You probably wouldn't write down a backwards copy of the string and then compare them letter by letter. More likely, you'd look at the first and last letters and see if they're the same, then move to the second and next-to-last, etc. Write code to do that; it's really much simpler than what you've done here.

@PeteBecker Indeed, OP modified the example (while still in Staging Grounds), reversing the text outputs, but I guess not the bool assignment. Didn't notice it then, but I think simply replacing it with 0 wouldn't be an edit that conflicts with the intent of original post.

Side note: std::reverse

string.h header has nothing to do with std::string, why do you include it?

why is palindrome a global? YOu only need it inside the function. And you want to include <string>. string.h is a totally different header

for (int i = text.length(); i >= 0; i--) - this is wrong, start here.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai: That reproduces perfectly.

@ShadowRanger ohkey i'll remove comments. The edits and discrepancy was too confusing.

Suspicious empty line at the start of the output

@Caleth It could be an artifact of formatting-- OP had two new line between the "output" line and the first line with text; it's impossible for anyone but them to confirm whether that was just two lines of formatting or one line of formatting and one line of empty output.

@TylerH no, it's because they start with the \0 at text[text.length()]

You issue in the question is int i = text.length(), you get "\0madam" in backwards with the unprintable first char.
It can be implemented easier. The easier code usually has less errors and is easy to debug.
bool is_palindrome(const std::string& text) {
  return text == std::string(text.rbegin(), text.rend());
}

Even better with inclusion <algorithm> library and not creating a temporary string object
bool is_palindrome(const std::string& text) {
  return std::equal(text.begin(), text.end(), text.rbegin());
}

Optimized for less CPU consumption time, but a longer code (taking into account that the first half matches the reversed second half in a palindrome):
bool is_palindrome(const std::string& text) {
  return std::equal(text.begin(), text.begin() + text.size() / 2, text.rbegin());
}

If you can use C++17 or newer one, the function parameters can be std::string_view
bool is_palindrome(std::string_view text);


I recommend using std::equal(text.begin(),text.end(),text.rbegin(),tex.rend()). this avoids dynamic allocation completely

And that does too much work...

you can also add mismatch algorithm for completeness

@Gene mismatch is not well suitable, it will be the longest code in my answer.

@3CxEZiVlQ -- mismatch has the same complexity as equal, it just returns iterators

Here is an example return std::get<0>(std::mismatch(std::cbegin(text), std::cend(text) + std::size(text)/2, std::crbegin(text))) == std::cend(text) + std::size(text)/2;

@Gene 1. Yet another example of a error prone long code. The both std::cend(text) + std::size(text)/2 result in undefined behavior. 2. Repetitions on the left and right side do not not look well. 3. You can omit all std:: due to Argument-dependent lookup.

@3CxEZiVlQ -- typos ☹️ but the idea is to show there are more ways to skin the cat then already mentioned. ADL is really irrelevant here, it's not like you are planning on anything other than std algos. Unless you want to be open to customization being explicit is better.

It's not undefined behaviour to do std::string s {"asdf"}; s[s.length()]. It's guaranteed by standard to return '\0' (see cppreference). Though it's probably not a good thing to learn as beginner, since it only holds for std::string and no other container.

Instead of int i = text.length() it should be i = text.length() - 1 because you make an extra loop.
Also, I've changed the return state.
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

bool is_palindrome(std::string text) {
    std::string backwards = "";
    for (int i = text.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        backwards = backwards + text[i];
    }
    std::cout << backwards << " and " << text << std::endl;
    if (text == backwards) {
        std::cout << "they are equal" << std::endl;
        return true;
    } else {
        std::cout << "they are not equal" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
}

int main() {
    std::cout << is_palindrome("madam") << "\n";
}


Alternatively, you could incorporate a predecrement into the conditional, e.g. for (int i = text.length(); --i >= 0;) {, so the decrement occurs in just one place, before each loop. Mostly personal preference. For strict type correctness, for (auto i = text.length(); i-- > 0;) { is arguably the best option (uses the correct size_type, doesn't overflow to negative).

for (std::size_t i = text.length(); i > 0; --i) backwards = backwards + text[i - 1];.

You can use a forward and backward iterator to compare the characters front/back to middle like this too.
And better you can test correctness at compile time
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

constexpr bool is_palindrome(std::string_view sv)
{
    auto front = sv.begin();
    auto back = sv.rbegin();

    for (;front < back.base(); ++front,++back)
    {
        if (*front != *back) return false;
    }

    return true;
}

int main()
{
    
    static_assert(is_palindrome("a"));
    static_assert(is_palindrome("aaa"));
    static_assert(is_palindrome("tacocat"));
    static_assert(!is_palindrome("ab"));
}


Just one more solution to the palindrome problem, that neither uses the already mentioned functions, nor creates temporaries for string literals:
auto is_palindrome(std::string_view text)
{
    return std::get<0>(std::mismatch(std::cbegin(text), std::cend(text), 
    std::crbegin(text))) == std::cend(text);
}

Edit: I benchmarked the performance of using half range std::cbegin(text) + std::size(text)/2 instead of going to std::cend(text). It showed slight degradation for short strings and slight improvement for long strings.

    #include<iostream>
    #incldue<string>
    using namespace std;
    
    bool is_palindrome(const string& text) {
        int length = text.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < length / 2; i++) {
            if (text[i] != text[length - i - 1]) {  
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    
    int main() {
        string word = "madam";
        if (is_palindrome(word)) {
            std::cout << word << " is a palindrome\n";
        } else {
            std::cout << word << " is not a palindrome\n";
        }
        return 0;
    }

I think you are taking string indexes wrong. The above maybe corrected and optimized solution.
Edit: Added pass by reference.

Thanks @Evg for pointing it out. edited the code.
